# Grouping WHERE clauses with Zend_Db_Table_Abstract

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-table

Does anyone know of a way to group where clauses with Zend_Db? Basically I have this query

```
$sql = $table->select()
             ->where('company_id = ?', $company_id)
             ->where('client_email = ?', $client_email)
             ->orWhere('client_email_alt = ?', $client_email);
```

Which is giving me this:

```
SELECT `clients`.* FROM `clients` WHERE (company_id = '1') AND (client_email = 'email@address.com') OR (client_email_alt = 'email@address.com')
```

But I need it to give me this, where the OR statement is grouped:

```
SELECT `clients`.* FROM `clients` WHERE (company_id = '1') AND ((client_email = 'email@address.com') OR (client_email_alt = 'email@address.com'))
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In order to achieve this, you have to construct the grouped clause within a single call to the `where` method.

If both values of conditions are the same, you can do this:

```
$select->where('client_email = ? OR client_email_alt = ?', $client_email)
```

If there are multiple placeholders within the string, the DB adapter's `quoteInto` method will replace all placeholders with the provided value.

If you need to group an `OR` with different values for each field, you have to manually quote the values. It's a bit more complex:

```
$select->where(
    $db->quoteInto('client_email = ?', $email1) . ' OR ' . $db->quoteInto('client_email_alt = ?', $email2)
); // $db is your instance of Zend_Db_Adapter_*
   // You can get it from a Zend_Db_Table_Abstract 
   //subclass by calling its getAdapter() method
```

Comment: What we need is $select->startWhereGroup() and $select->endWhereGroup().

Comment: The Zend Framework 2 \Zend\Db\Sql\Select looks promising in this regard.

Comment: Awesome! thanks Jason, I have been looking for this solution for ages. It works like a treat. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use `getPart()` to get WHERE statement and then connect sub-queries.

```php
$select->where('client_email = ?', $client_email)
       ->orWhere('client_email_alt = ?', $client_email);

$subquery = $select->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::WHERE);
$select ->reset(Zend_Db_Select::WHERE);
$select ->where('company_id = ?', $company_id)
        ->where(implode(' ',$subquery));
```

Answer (score 1):

For Zend Framework Version 2, things differ a bit:

See http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.2/classes/Zend.Db.Sql.Predicate.Predicate.html#nest

```
$table->select()
     ->where(['company_id'=> $company_id])
     ->nest
         ->where('client_email = ?', $client_email)
         ->or
         ->where('client_email_alt = ?', $client_email)
     ->unnest();
```

works fine and feels much cleaner than the ZF1 methods.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to combine AND/OR statements but including OR statements conditionally, adding them only in some cases. This solution is an adaptation of what I did, based on small modifications of the accepted answer.

```
$sql = $table->select()
         ->where('company_id = ?', $company_id);

$orWhereClauses = [];
// We could add a conditional statement to add this statement
$orWhereClauses[] = $db->quoteInto('client_email = ?', $email1);
// Same applies to this statement
$orWhereClauses[] = $db->quoteInto('client_email_alt = ?', $email2);

$sql->where(implode(" OR ", $orWhereClauses));
```

Answer (score 0):

In first you can generate subquery, then get "WHERE" part and insert into main query

```
$subquery = $db->select();
$subquery->orWhere('a>10');
$subquery->orWhere('b<20');
etc..

$subquery = $subquery->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::WHERE);
$select->where(implode(' ',$subquery));
```