# Adding complex WHERE conditions to a Zend_Db_Select

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Zend Framework Complex Where Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899795/zend-framework-complex-where-statement)

How do I add something like this to a Zend_Db_Select while still using quoting?

```
SELECT x FROM y WHERE (a=1 OR b=2) AND (c=3 OR d=4)
```

I have seen where() and orWhere(), but I see no way of grouping them with brackets. I realize that I could just write this:

```
->where('(a=1 OR b=2) AND (c=3 OR d=4)')
```

But ideally I would like to have 4 separate calls to where() to be able to use the second parameter for quoting (assuming the values 1, 2, 3 etc. are user generated input).

Is there any way to do this in the pure fluent style?

Comment: I did some research and found [this post](http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=69&t=6413#p21696) that suggests using `getPart` but have not tested it.

Comment: Looks like it could work, but is pretty counterintuitive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way to do this in the pure fluent style?

Short answer: no.

As you mention, you can use `orWhere` to write conditions like `(a = ?) OR (b = ?)`.

> Zend_Db_Select automatically puts parentheses around each expression you specify using the where() or orWhere() methods. This helps to ensure that Boolean operator precedence does not cause unexpected results.

However it is [not possible to nest `AND` and `OR` conditions](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-182) in the way you wish.

If you wrote this:

```
->where('a=?', $a)
->orWhere('b=?', $b)
->where('c=?', $c)
->orWhere('d=?', $d)
```

It would result in SQL similar to this:

```
(a=1) OR (b=2) AND (c=3) OR (d=4)
```

Which would be interpreted as follows (not what you want):

```
(a=1) OR ((b=2) AND (c=3)) OR (d=4)
```

Alternatives:

- Write the SQL by hand.
- Use `quoteInto` as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179279/grouping-where-clauses-with-zend-db-table-abstract).

Comment: @WolfgangStengel: I don't think you are missing something. I think the API is missing something.

Comment: That was what I was afraid of. Thanks.