# use zend db with whare and orwhere when orwhere are in ()

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

hi i want create this sql in zend framework dbclass

```
selec * from table where type = 2 AND (name LIKE '%4%' OR name LIKE '%5%')
```

how i can do this with zend where and orwhere?

using normal mode will generate this sql

```
 $this->select()->from($this->_name)->where('type = ?', $type)->orwhere('name LIKE ?', '%'.4.'%');
```

this is not what i need

also i think i can use having in this case , is this a good idea?

Comment: You can't group where clauses on Zend. The only solution is as in @Tim Fountain's answer - to group clauses like a normal query string. Note: I'm not sure for `ZF2`, maybe there is a solution for this.

Comment: thanks but i used 
 $this->select()->from($this->_name)->having('type = ?', $type)->orwhere('name LIKE ?', '%'.4.'%');
now it's work ... is this a good statement ?

Comment: If this didn't work for you, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179279/grouping-where-clauses-with-zend-db-table-abstract

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want:

```
$this->select()
     ->from($this->_name)
     ->where('type = ?', $type)
     ->where('name LIKE ? OR name LIKE ?', array('%'.4.'%', '%'.5.'%');
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this.

Comment: This is not working for me. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1179410/281087